# How do I set environment variables in my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, environment-variables

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 and trying to create environment variables accessible only in my application (as opposed to storing them in a ~/.bashrc file or some OS-specific solution).  So I created the file “config/environment_variables.yml” with

```
development:
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: 999995268318-o5ejue1pgtsjoid0f0k8r7lcksfse6hk.apps.googleusercontent.com
  GOOGLE_SECRET: 28bfoTU_RbRKkdxv7_wkNzw5
  FACEBOOK_KEY: 1588888667329742
  FACEBOOK_SECRET: 4444g1faeb11111e5392892d397b79f8e
production:
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: 999995268318-o5ejue1pgtsjoid0f0k8r7lcksfse6hk.apps.googleusercontent.com
  GOOGLE_SECRET: 28bfoTU_RbRKkdxv7_wkNzw5
  FACEBOOK_KEY: 1588888667329742
  FACEBOOK_SECRET: 4444g1faeb11111e5392892d397b79f8e
```

and then I created the file “config/initializers/environment_variables.rb”

```
module EnvironmentVariablesExample
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.before_configuration do
      env_file = Rails.root.join("config", 'environment_variables.yml').to_s

      if File.exists?(env_file)
        YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
          ENV[key.to_s] = value
        end # end YAML.load_file
      end # end if File.exists?
    end # end config.before_configuration
  end # end class
end # end module
```

but when I startup my server on my local machine with “rails s,” I get this error

```
Exiting
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/pushupmoose/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:8:in `[]=': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/pushupmoose/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Application>'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/pushupmoose/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:7:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/pushupmoose/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:7:in `block in <class:Application>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:53:in `before_configuration'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/pushupmoose/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:3:in `<class:Application>'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/pushupmoose/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:2:in `<module:EnvironmentVariablesExample>'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/pushupmoose/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    …
```

What am I doing wrong in my environment set up above?  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: If you keep the env. variables in the application itself you might as well not change anything correct?  The main reason to use environment variables is in case you ever push this app to git and your secret_key among other things are shown to the public.  If you want to keep things inside the app and not stored off site, I'd recommend adding these sensitive files to gitignore at the very least.  If you are collaboring with others you can use "git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>" which will stop tracking changes but wont remove from the repo. Just change the info after first commit.

Comment: Yes, this file will go into .gitignore but how does putting this file in the .gitignore cure the error message?

Comment: try `puts key.to_s;puts value` before `ENV[key.to_s] = value` and see where the server stopped...it will tell u the culprit variable that is causing the bug...just a wild guess, maybe need a `value.to_s`

Comment: +1 to convert values to string. You should use [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem, which does the heavy work for you and it's very easy to implement.

Comment: I <3 Figaro! Especially because I deploy on Heroku and it makes that so easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is not because of how you're setting the value but because of the value you are setting.

Your `FACEBOOK_KEY` values are numeric which the `YAML.load_file` will respect. It will then try and store those numeric values in the `ENV`. However, `ENV` only likes string values.

```
2.2.1 :019 > ENV['test'] = 1
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
from (irb):19:in `[]='
from (irb):19

2.2.1 :020 > ENV['test'] = '1'
=> "1"
```

So, if you wrap your `FACEBOOK_KEY` values in double quotes you should be okay:

```
development:
  FACEBOOK_KEY: "1588888667329742"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use gem called dotenv-rails. The documentation is here:
https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv
simply in Gemfile write:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

Then run bundle install.
After that create a file in main directory of app named '.env.local' and in that file write:

```
export GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=YOUR_ID
```

(ID without any quotes) And the point where you want to use just write:

```
ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']
```

And for production just create another file '.env.production'. 
Remember to call '.env*' in gitignore.

For more information on environment variable in development and production checkout this blog post: [https://sulmanbaig.com/blogs/using-environment-variables-in-rails-heroku-capistrano](http://sulmanbaig.com/blog/using-environment-variables-in-rails-heroku-capistrano)

Comment: Sulman Baig the link is broken 
I did all of what you said but my question is what I should do for heroku for example.
Should I add for example ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'] or the real value?

Comment: Try using figaro gem its updated one and easy to use https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro